# fread does not read the entire file

Tags: c, ubuntu, fread

I used `fread` to read the entire file but I am getting only the first of it, why is that?

My code:

```
#define MAXBUFLEN 4096

int main(){
int ret =0;
    char source[MAXBUFLEN + 1];
    FILE *fp = fopen("test", "r");

    if (fp != NULL) 
    {
        rewind(fp);
        ret = fread(source, 1, MAXBUFLEN, fp);
        printf("ret : %d %s",ret,source);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The file text:

```
/# cat test
/usr/sbin/sshd-p 1234-o LoginGraceTime=30-o ClientAliveInterval=600-o ClientAliveCountMax=0-o TCPKeepAlive=no-o MaxSessions=1-o MaxStartups=1-o MaxAuthTries=3
```

My program output :

```
ret : 167  /usr/sbin/sshd
```

What is the easiest way of reading this entire file? (which is not standard and not end with \n)?

Comment: is there by any chance a `'\0'` byte right after `/usr/sbin/sshd` in the file ?

Comment: also print the return value of `fread(source, 1, MAXBUFLEN, fp);`

Comment: `fread()` does **not** place a string in `source[]`. Using the content of `source[]` as a string is erroneous.

Comment: fread return 167

Comment: Please answer the question by Sander. If necessary use a hex-editor to find out. Alternatively, manually create a file which only contains the printable letters as shown here.

Comment: I checked your code, it's reading the full sample file that you've provided. fread is returning 159.

Comment: There are 158 visible characters shown in the sample input. Fread counts 167. The difference can be explained by on \0 before each of the "-" in visible sample input and one blank or 0 at the end. I.e. please answer Sanders question.

Comment: Not your problem, but: `rewind(fp)` is unnecessary.

Comment: It looks like you are debugging a command line string you have built.  It looks like there's a problem with the way you're building that string.  I notice things like `sshd-p` where I would expect `sshd -p`, and `=30-o` where I would expect `=30 -o`'.  It's likely that you are somehow inserting `'\0'` characters, instead of spaces, when concatenating the arguments.  That would explain the symptom you're seeing.

Comment: sander right ther was 0 chacter betwen each the file

Comment: `printf("ret : %d %s",ret,source);` is a problem had the text file not contained any _null character_.  In that case, `printf()` is attempting to print `source` as a _string_, yet `source` is not known to have a terminating _null character_.

Comment: "easiest way of reading this entire file?" --> code did that.  The trouble here is not in reading, but in printing.

Comment: The easiest way to print the file after reading it: `fwrite(source, 1, ret, stdout);`

Answer (score 0):

Answer : there was 0 between each word in this file, it was not standard word but ^@ which is recored seperate in Linux . The code was fixed by this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeNewLine(char * str,int len);

#define MAXBUFLEN 4096

int main(){
    char source[MAXBUFLEN + 1];
    FILE *fp = fopen("test", "r");
    int ret =0;
    if (fp != NULL) 
    {
        rewind(fp);
        ret = fread(source, 1,MAXBUFLEN, fp);
        removeNewLine(source,ret);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}

void removeNewLine(char * str,int len){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<len;i++) {
        if((int)str[i]==0 )
        {
            str[i]=' ';
        }
    }
    str[len] = 0;
    printf("%s",str);
 }
```